# How to use upgrader package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, updates, flutter-packages

How can I use the use the upgrader package in flutter, like how can I make an AppCast file and use AppCast Configuration for my app and how do I show release notes on the alert. And how do I get the right versions. This package https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader/example